# Function template overloading resolution involving pointers

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Given a template and a more specialized overload:

```
template <typename T>
const T& some_func(const T& a, const T& b) 
{
    std::cout << "Called base template\n";
    return (a < b) ? a : b; 
}

template <typename T>
T* const& some_func(T* const& a, T* const& b) 
{
    std::cout << "Called T* overload\n";
    return (*a < *b) ? a : b; 
}
```

Then the following works as expected:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << some_func(5.3, 6.2) << "\n";
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;
    double *p = &a;
    double *q = &b;
    const double *ret = some_func(p, q); 
    std::cout << *ret << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

With the first printing `Called base template`, the second printing `Called T* overload`. If we replace the overload signature with:

```
template <typename T>
const T*& some_func(const T*& a, const T*& b)
```

then the second call now calls the base template. Given that `int const& x` is equivalent to `const int& x`, am I incorrect in assuming `T* const&` is equivalent to `const T*&`? Why is the first version resolved properly while the second is not?

Comment: It's not a specialization here.

Comment: @Yuushi - We are marking words here, but you have two overloaded functions, where the second one is *more specialized* that the first. However, it is not a template specialization, it is two separate function templates. :-)

Comment: @Flexo Also true. I'll edit the question to reflect that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are incorrect. In `const T*&` T is const, in `T* const&` the pointer (T*) is const.

The change happens when you shift `const` to the right of `*`. `const T*&` and `T const *&` are equivalent but `T* const&` is different. Typedefs can help, given

```
typedef T *TPtr;
```

`const TPtr&` is equivalent to `TPtr const &` is equivalent to `T* const &`.

Declarators in C/C++ are hard to parse (for a human). Even the inventor of C said so.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it should be somewhat obvious when I think about it, but I guess there's no better way to burn it into my brain than asking a silly question...

Answer (score 2):

`T const &` and `const T &` are identical; and `U const *` and `const U *` are identical.

But `S &` and `T const &` are *not* the same even for `T = S`. What you have is even worse, namely `S = U const *` and `T = U *`.